# Error importing variable from another file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tkinter

I am building a program that uses a very large variable, so I'm giving it its own file. When trying to import the variable I keep getting errors.

let's say `file1` has my code and `file2` has the variable, my `file2` looks something like this:

```
array = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

and my `file1` looks something like this:

```
import tkinter
import file2
class test:
    def print_var():
        print(file2.array)
test().print_var()
```

Whenever I run it, it tells me that `'module' object does not have attribute 'array'`. I tried putting it in class and importing the class but that didn't work either. It feels like I'm missing something important, any help would be appreciated.

If it matters: the variable is an array, **the files are in the same folder**, and the project is using tkinter.

EDIT: This project consists of 3 files: a `main` file, the variable file(`file2`), and `file1` which is imported into `main`. Both the `main` file and `file1` import `file2`, could this be causing the issue?

EDIT 2: In response to Mike, The actual code is referenced, however I didn't want to use the actual code because I think dumping 300 lines of code onto here would be frowned upon. I have changed my example to reflect your suggestion.

EDIT 3: I put an `__init__.py` file into the folder to no avail.

EDIT 4: in response to Mike's comment. Good point. I'm sorry I didn't provide enough information, I tried to only include necessary information but obviously I missed quite a lot. I'll be sure to provide better context next time.

Comment: What is your folder structure?

Comment: does the folder have an `__init__.py`

Comment: See my updated answer. I have a suspicion you are using a package for your files and you need to apply the package name to your import. `import PackageName.file2 as file2`.

Comment: *I think dumping 300 lines of code onto here would be frowned upon.*... Yes posting a large amount of code would be bad here however your example needs to be able to reproduce the error you are getting. Based on the code you have provided we do not get the same error and thus makes it harder to troubleshoot. Did you test your example before posting it? Do you get the same error with your example as your main code gets?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing should work. 
Here is a working example:

```
+
- file1.py
- file2.py


#file1.py
array = ['x', 'y']

#file2.py
import file1
print(file1.array)
# this also works
from file1 import array
print(array)


# Bash
❯❯❯ python file2.py
['x', 'y']
['x', 'y']
```

Common causes for Attribute Errors related to import errors:

- Name clashes (eg. you have a folder and a file with the same name, and the wrong one is being imported)
- Circular Imports (file1 imports file2, but file2 also imports file1)

To troubleshoot this, you can try:

```
# Ensure correct file is being imported
>>> print(file2.__file__)
'~/dev/file2.pyc'

# Check the variables in the imported module's scope - note 'array' is listed
>>> dir(file2)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'array']
```

- Make sure there are no circular imports - if `__init__.py` is involved you have to be extra careful as the code inside of it will run when the parent folder is used. This can cause code to be imported earlier than you think

## Note on Circular Imports

If I include a circular import in the working code sample above,
note I get the exact same error you are getting:

```
#file1.py
import file2  # Circular Import
array = ['x', 'y']

#file2.py
import file1
print(dir(file1))
print(file1.array)

# Bash - Note unlike example above, "array" is not included
# in the module's scope due to the circular import
❯❯❯ python file2.py
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
def print_var():
```

To:

```
def print_var(self):
```

Update:

Also if you are using a package in your file path you may need to inclue the package name. For example I am using Eclipse ID and if I use a package to store all my files then I need to do something like this for the import.

```
import PackageName.file2 as file2

class test:
    def print_var(self):
        print(file2.array)

test().print_var()
```

If you do not do this you will get a similar error you are getting.

```
AttributeError: module 'file2' has no attribute 'array'
```

When you have a class and you want to call a function inside that class you need to define that function as a class method so it can be accessed from outside the class.

By adding `self` to the function it becomes a class method and now can be called with:

```
test().print_var()
```

On that note your example does not include a call to the test class so I am assuming you are either missing this call all-together or just forgot it in your example. Either way you will need it.

Based on your question I built 2 files.

file1.py:

```
import file2

class test:
    def print_var(self):
        print(file2.array)

test().print_var()
```

file2.py:

```
array = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: You are correct that self should be included as an argument, 
but the error caused by its omission would be different and not related to the attribute error in question `(unbound method print_var() must be called with test instance)`

Comment: @gtalarico I get no such error and it works fine on my end. As you can see from my screen shot of the console window.

Comment: Hi Mike- Let me try to clarify my comment:
the first part of your answer suggests that's the solution (change `print_var()` to `print_var(self)`

Omitting `self` would raise a TypeError(unbound method called w/out instance)
but the error mentioned in the question is related to an attribute error (not being 
able to access a variable inside an imported module)

In other words, your answer is correct in the sense `self` should be added to the method definition, but it does not answer the original question (module attribute error)

Comment: @gtalarico Well with the comments in the OPs question and the structure they are showing I feel like there is some conflicting information about what the files actually look like. So my answer servers to correct the code displayed rather than the error mentioned as it does not at all coincide with the code being presented.